# WCF simple serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a common class (common meaning it is defined it its own library, used by both the client and service)

```
    [Serializable]
    Class C1
    {
        string s1;
        string s2;
    }
```

in my WCF service I create an instance, populate and return it:
this is the interface:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface myInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        c1 GetClass(string number);
    }
```

here is my service class:

```
    public class ColorTracker : myInterface
    {

        public c1 GetObj(string value)
        {
            c1 theColor = new c1();
            c1.s1= "value1";
            c1.s2= "value2";
            return  c1;
        }
    }
```

client:

```
    using (ServieClient bmClient = new ServiceClient())
    {
        c1 theColor;

        theColor =  (c1) bmClient.GetObj("test");

    }
```

It all kind of works, but I can only access the return data through the backing fields.  I would like to instantiate the object (or i suppose it could be a structure since its only data, not state)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You want to instantiate an object - what object? The object is already instantiated in the service, isn't it?

Comment: On the client side the object is populated from a database operation.  I want to get that data on the client side.  In the example I can not get data from my object "theColor" by calling getter methods (theColor.s1()) i can only get the data by pulling it out of the backing methods that reside in the generated proxy code.

Comment: Database on the client side? Not that I understand your problem now, but maybe you should make `s1` and `s2` a property by appending `{get; set;}`.

Comment: no, the service will populate the object via a database call.  I have to get all that data back to the client consuming the service, all in all it will be 20 or 30 fields.  I wanted to be able to populate an object, or a structure on the client side with the returned data by deserializing or unmarshalling it.

Comment: @JerseyDuke: in the generated proxy code, `s1` is not a method - it is a property. You should use it this way - `theColor.s1` and not this way `theColor.s1()`.  Was this your problem?

Answer (score 0):

WCF does not care about `[Serializable]` attribute. If you want you class to be a data contract, you should mark it with the `[DataContract]` attribute instead.

Also, convert your fields to properties, and mark them with the `[DataMember]` attribute.

```
[DataContract]
Class C1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string s1 {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string s2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: And what would this change other that having *private* properties instead of fields?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the question. Which problem does this solve now?

Comment: @HighCore: WCF _does_ care about `[Serializable]` and also, you dont need explicit opt-in `[DataMember]` with it. `[Serializable]` class's members _will_ show up in the metadata and will be part of generated proxy.

Answer (score 0):

When your attribute is [Serializable] then in the client side you can just use private fields! but,since your properties are Auto genenrated fiels {get;set;} ,in the client side you can see auto generated **prop__BackingFields**;

you can Refactor your properties like this:

```
[Serializable ]
public class MyData
{
    private string _prop1;

    public  string Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set { _prop1 = value; }
    }
```

but I think the best way to code your issue is this:

1.Define two data contracts:

```
[DataContract  ]
public class ServerSideFilledData
{...}and
[DataContract  ]
public class ClientSideFilledData
{...}
```

2.Define a Message Contract with two MessageBody Attributes:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MixedServerandClientSideData
{
    private ClientSideFilledData clientSideFilledData;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public ClientSideFilledData ClientSideFilledData
    {
        get { return clientSideFilledData; }
        set { clientSideFilledData = value; }
    }

    private ClientSideFilledData serverSideFilledData;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public ClientSideFilledData ServerSideFilledData
    {
        get { return serverSideFilledData; }
        set { serverSideFilledData = value; }
    }
}
```

3.Instead of Serializable Or DataContract, use your Message for exchanging data between cient and server

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    MixedServerandClientSideData DoWork();
}
```

4.I think you know the continue ,initialize and fill your data in convenient sides.